# openCV Error module 'cv2.face' has no attribute 'createEigenFaceRecognizer'

Tags: python, opencv

I am using python 3.7 and latest version of openCV. When i try to create an `EigenFaceRecognizer`. This error pops up "module 'cv2.face' has no attribute `createEigenFaceRecognizer`. I have got this bellow code from a Gitub repo.

```
recognise = cv2.face.createEigenFaceRecognizer(15, 4000)
recognise.load("Recogniser/trainingDataEigan.xml")
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the `face` module is in the `opencv-contrib` library. You can install it with

```
pip uninstall opencv-contrib-python
pip install opencv-contrib-python --no-cache-dir
```

Also the function got changed to this. `load` was replaced with `read`

```
import cv2

recognise = cv2.face.EigenFaceRecognizer_create()  
recognise.read("Recogniser/trainingDataEigan.xml")
```