# openCV Error 'module' object has no attribute 'createEigenFaceRecognizer'

Tags: python, opencv, face-recognition

I'm using python 2.7.16 OpenCV 4.1.1 when I run my error is `python 'module' object has no attribute 'createEigenFaceRecognizer'` I already searched
this error because Version of OpenCV but I can't find createEigenFaceRecognizer() in OpenCV 4.1.1 help me pleas.

I have try "cv2.face.createEigenFaceRecognizer()" and "cv2.face_LBPHFaceRecognizer()" but have same error

This my function that error

```py
def train_model(path):

    [images, labels, people]= get_images(sys.argv[1], (256, 256))

    labels= np.asarray(labels, dtype= np.int32)

    print("Initializing eigen FaceRecognizer and training...")
    sttime= time.clock()
    eigen_model= cv2.createEigenFaceRecognizer()
    eigen_model.train(images, labels)
    print("\tCompleted training in "+ str(time.clock()- sttime)+ " Secs!")

    return [eigen_model, people]
```

this when I call function

```py
    arg_one= sys.argv[1]
    eigen_model, people= train_model(arg_one)
```

Comment: did you `import cv2` before running the code?

Comment: @Aaron_ab Yes, I did.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [openCV Error module 'cv2.face' has no attribute 'createEigenFaceRecognizer'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57082768/opencv-error-module-cv2-face-has-no-attribute-createeigenfacerecognizer)